Передать стейт модального окна в в другой файл js
необходимо передать стейт модального окна в другой файл: если модальное окно открыто, то совершить определенные действия. Не могу понять как из этого кода передать стейт...
const modals = () => {
  function bindModal(triggerSelector, modalSelector, closeSelector) {
    const trigger = document.querySelectorAll(triggerSelector),
      modal = document.querySelector(modalSelector),
      close = document.querySelector(closeSelector);

    trigger.forEach((item) => {
      item.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
        if (e.target) {
          e.preventDefault();
        }
        modal.style.display = "block";
        document.body.style.overflow = "hidden";
      });
    });
    close.addEventListener("click", () => {
      modal.style.display = "none";
      document.body.style.overflow = "";
    });

    modal.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
      if (e.target == modal) {
        modal.style.display = "none";
        document.body.style.overflow = "";
      }
    });
  }

  bindModal(
    ".popup_engineer_btn",
    ".popup_engineer",
    ".popup_engineer .popup_close"
  );
};


Что в вашем коде стейт? Передать стейт куда? Дополните вопрос необходимыми деталями

мне необходимо в другом файле прописать: если модальное окно открыто, то совершить определенные действия(знаю как), а вот как в другом файле вызвать функцию если модальное окно открыто (как из этого файла вызвать стейт - модальное окно открыто)

Спасибо огромное!!!
